# Bootstrap Tooltip Placement Bottom not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my bootstrap tooltip work with dynamically created content and I was told to use this but it seems to not be placing my tooltips to the bottom what is wrong with my code

The javascript:

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[rel=tooltip]',
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MyxhA/

EDIT:
`$('[rel=tooltip]')` doesn't work on dynamically added content

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/VXctp/612/

Answer (score 5):

don't attach that to the `body` simply use the selector

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/MyxhA/2/

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

Comment: works fine for all the directions, except for `'right'`